# How to another site button click get text For Chrome Extension JS

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

before sorry I'm not speak English. 
I want to do example:

```
<input type="text" id="example">
<input type="submit" id="test">
```

When the test button is clicked with chrome extension that information here, I want to reach before they are sent.

Comment: <input type="text" id="example"> <input type="submit" id="test">

Comment: code is a universal language - post what you've tried so far, it may go a long way to explain your question